# KeyError: 'kivy.garden.knob'

Tags: kivy

im trying to use this in my kivy project but keep getting this keyerror. Ive tried a coupe different trouble shooting things, but i figured someone here might be able to help.

```
Nolans-MacBook-Pro:~ nolandonley$ kivy 
/Users/nolandonley/Desktop/Kivy/main1.py
Purge log fired. Analysing...
Purge finished!
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in 
/Applications/Kivy.app/Contents/Resources/.kivy/logs/kivy_18-05-28_32.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.10.0
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.5.0 (default, Jun 11 2017, 01:10:38) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.30.5)]
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 194 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_imageio, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [OSC         ] using <multiprocessing> for socket
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL ES 2" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <gl>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'2.1 INTEL-10.32.48'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Inc.'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel Iris Pro OpenGL Engine'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 2, 1
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.20'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/nolandonley/Desktop/Kivy/main1.py", line 17, in <module>
 from kivy.garden.knob import Knob
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 664, in _load_unlocked
   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 636, in _load_backward_compatible
 KeyError: 'kivy.garden.knob'
```

Comment: Have you installed Kivy Garden Knob?

Comment: i have garden installed knob and updated it

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my issue, at least temporarily. I had to move the knob.py file to my garden effects folder an import from there because for some reason importing from the garden folder was giving be issues.